# Bounds for LibraryFunction arguments of integer type

Tags: librarylink

I am trying to load a function written in C++ using [`LibaryFunctionLoad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LibaryFunctionLoad.html). Doing so, I have encountered an issue I believe to be a bug (I wanted to ask here first in case I'm missing something obvious):

Take e.g. the following C/C++ function:

```Cpp
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int inc(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res)
{
    MArgument_setInteger(Res, MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]) + 1);

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Load it in MMA:

```
inc = LibraryFunctionLoad[NotebookDirectory[] <> "inc.dll", "inc", {_Integer}, _Integer];
```

This works mostly as expected:

```
inc[5]
(* 6 *)

inc[2^63]
(* Error, should be machine-sized integer *)

inc[2^63-1]
(* -9223372036854775808 *)

% == -2^63
(* True *)   

inc[-2^63+1]
(* -9223372036854775806 *)
```

However:

```
inc[-2^63]
(* Error, should be machine-sized integer *)
```

As you can see, it seems as if the bound check for machine-sized integers is off by one on the negative end. Is my observation correct or am I missing something? What speaks for this interpretation is the fact that `inc[2^63-1]` correctly returns `-2^63` but this returned value can not be passed back to the function.

### Update

I have received the following reply from Wolfram support:

> Yes, this is a slightly unfortunate consequence of the discrepancy
>   between the machine integer range in C and in WL. Specifically, -2^63
>   is a machine integer in C, but is not Developer`MachineIntegerQ.
>
> The reasons for this design decision go far back.
>
> The actual machine integer -2^63 is excluded from the definition of
>   "machine integer in WL" even though it is one, because that allows an
>   optimization -- don't need to check for packing/unpacking when
>   negating a machine integer matrix.

I will try to find the easiest workaround for this issue and will update the post once I found one.

Comment: Probably this ``Developer`$MaxMachineInteger``

Comment: @halirutan what do you want to say with that? Normally, integer bounds for signed integers are $-2^{n-1},...,2^{n-1}-1$.

Comment: This *does* work: `RawArray["Integer64", {-2^63}]` (for raw arrays it would seem to be more important to accurately represent the full range).

Comment: Interestingly, it is still possible to return a packed array containing `-2^63` from LibraryLink.  Negating this packed array will trigger unpacking.  I guess not all packed arrays are the same.

Answer (score 4):

This is a long comment.

It could be a bug, but it could also be some weirdness in the handling of machine integers.  I think the only thing you can do is contact Wolfram Support, and let us know what they said.

Mathematica's behaviour seems much too consistent for this to be a "bug" (i.e. something they overlooked).

```
Developer`MachineIntegerQ[-2^63]
(* False *)

Developer`PackedArrayQ[
 Developer`ToPackedArray[{-2^63 + 1}]
 ]
(* True *)

Developer`PackedArrayQ[
 Developer`ToPackedArray[{-2^63 + 1}] - 1
 ]
(* False *)
```

If I try to return this value from a LibraryLink library, the result also isn't a machine integer according to these functions.

However, if I try to return a single-element `Integer` array containing a value, then it is still treated as a packed array.

This very last finding is inconsistent with the rest and suggests a possible bug to me.

---

The LTemplate code I used for testing (for reference):

```
<< LTemplate`

SetDirectory@CreateDirectory[];

tem = LClass["Bounds", {
    LFun["lowest", {}, Integer],
    LFun["lowestArr", {}, {Integer, 1}]
    }];

code = "
  struct Bounds {

      mint lowest() { return (1L << 63); }

      mma::IntTensorRef lowestArr() {
        auto arr = mma::makeVector<mint>(1);
        arr[0] = (1L << 63);
        return arr;
    }
  };";
Export["Bounds.h", code, "String"];

CompileTemplate[tem]

LoadTemplate[tem]

obj = Make[Bounds];

obj@"lowest"[]
(* -9223372036854775808 *)

Developer`PackedArrayQ[obj@"lowestArr"[]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I have updated the main question with a reply from Wolfram support - it seems that your conclusion was correct

Answer (score 4):

My comment was only a pointer to the bound in *Mathematica*. I too believe that the bound check is weird. Let me give a simple example that probably makes it a bit clearer than the ones from Mathe172

```
dec = Compile[{{i, _Integer, 0}},
   i - 1,
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
```

When we decrement the smallest possible integer, the sign should flip and we should end with the largest possible integer. This gives us a warning and falls back to Kernel evaluation:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Therefore, the smallest possible machine integer must be larger:

```
dec[-2^63 + 1]
(* -9223372036854775808 *)
```

However, note that we end up with the **negative** number -2^63 which was claimed before to not be a machine integer. Therefore, I believe the bound-check is off as well.

One possible explanation is that not all integer representations are asymmetric like the twos-complement. In fact, all other ones I know are symmetric (ones-complement, sign-representation). Probably the bound-check is a compromise to work on all machines.

Comment: This is a bit similar to how it is possible to return `Infinity` from a LibraryFunction, but not pass it to it. If the `Infinity` is in a packed array, it will cause weird behaviour unless the array is unpacked first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I have updated the main question with a reply from Wolfram support - apparently, the reason for the decision was really the symmetry of the integer representation